# PHP DateTime Handle EDT switch

Tags: php, datetime

I have a loop for pulling data from DB, it's pretty complex however I've setup a sample code. The idea of this code is that it goes from X hour to Y hour, however with the EDT switch happening this Sunday at 2AM, the loop does not continue correctly.

I ofcourse could add a else/if however is there a proper solution for this?

Sample code:

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-11-05 22:00:00', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

foreach(range(1,48) as $i) {
    echo $date->format('Y/m/d H:i')."<br/>";

    $date->add(new DateInterval('PT15M'));
}
```

Example output:

```
2016/11/05 22:00

2016/11/05 22:15

2016/11/05 22:30

2016/11/05 22:45

2016/11/05 23:00

2016/11/05 23:15

2016/11/05 23:30

2016/11/05 23:45

2016/11/06 00:00

2016/11/06 00:15

2016/11/06 00:30

2016/11/06 00:45

2016/11/06 01:00

2016/11/06 01:15

2016/11/06 01:30

2016/11/06 01:45

2016/11/06 01:00

2016/11/06 01:15

2016/11/06 01:30

2016/11/06 01:45

2016/11/06 01:00

2016/11/06 01:15

2016/11/06 01:30

2016/11/06 01:45

2016/11/06 01:00

2016/11/06 01:15

2016/11/06 01:30

2016/11/06 01:45

2016/11/06 01:00

2016/11/06 01:15

2016/11/06 01:30

2016/11/06 01:45

2016/11/06 01:00

2016/11/06 01:15

...
```

This loop carries on until foreach is finished, where it keeps resetting to 1AM at 2AM, is there a different way to increase the timestamp via DateTime? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So when it turns 2:00 the clock goes back to 1:00 as it should.

Comment: The problem is that it enters in an infinite loop because it always goes back to 1..

Comment: It seems it works fine for php 5.3.. so it is a bug for newest versions?

Comment: It's almost as if it doesn't know that it already did the 1 hour adjustment. That;s what i'm trying to overcome. This is running on php 5.6

Comment: Keeping your server and date/time calculations to UTC avoids this kind of problem. You can then convert to local time for presentation.

Comment: `"It's almost as if it doesn't know that it already did the 1 hour adjustment."` How could it know?

Comment: @vascowhite an internal variable? Why not?